# Getting the system language in C or C++

Tags: c++, cross-platform, locale

I've tried searching, But I have'nt found anything like this.

I have an cross-platform software (Windows, GNU/Linux and OSX), and I dont know how to get the operational system current language, like pt_BR, en_US, and those things.

It have to work on all systems, as the source code is the same for all of them.

Comment: Use some cross-platform framework, e.g. [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) or perhaps [Boost](http://boost.org/) or just C++11

Comment: The software has tons of code, I just need to upgrade it.

Answer (score 7):

I'm surprised you did not stumble across this, because it's **standard C++**::

[`ios::getloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/getloc) is something you should have a look at, but even more importantly [`std::locale()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) (code snippet from the [`locale.name` docs on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale/name)):

```
std::cout << "The default locale is " << std::locale().name() << '\n'
          << "The user's locale is " << std::locale("").name() << '\n'
          << "A nameless locale is " << loc.name() << '\n';
```

Comment: I'm not an c++ programmer, Its my first time with the language, programmed on C/Python/PHP only.

Comment: @user3721069: still, googling for *C++ get locale* is bound to point you at the right ressources.

Comment: This function is only returning "C" for me

Comment: @user3721069: "C" is the default locale. And things are complicated by the C++ locale stuff not being defined as a wrapper of the C locale stuff, and by in particular g++ having unholy connections between the two. For the C level locale stuff do a `setlocale( "", LC_ALL )` at start of `main`, and it's possible that that fixes things wrt. to the g++ C++ level.

Comment: @user3721069, as Alf. said, if it returns C, then your locale *is* C, from C++ perspective. You might try to go the "libc" route as Alf recommended, but to be honest, I never had problems with GCC/g++ localization, so from a blind guess, I'd assume if C++'s `std::locale` tells you `C`, then libc's locale probably won't be more detailed.

Comment: This will not give the system language nor region

Comment: locale known to the operating system, such as "POSIX" or "en_US.UTF8" or "English_United States.1252". If the locale is not a copy of a system-supplied locale, the string "*" is returned.

Comment: Rather use `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
  cout << "LC_ALL: " << setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL) << endl;`